# Change each image on click Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a small issue trying to get working a catalog product list in Magento based script wich has associated images to the product list and on click it change the main image.

The issue is that on click All images are changed.

How can i do to change only the clicked image?
And move the main image to data-main-image-src clicked.

Below the code im using.

HTML:

```
<li class="item first">
    <a href="http://localhost/product.html" title="Product" class="product-image"><img class="MainImage" src="//lorempixel.com/60/60/food/1/" width="155" height="145" alt="Product"></a>
    <div class="moreviewslist">
        <img data-main-image-src="//lorempixel.com/60/60/food/2/" src="//lorempixel.com/60/60/food/2/">
        <img data-main-image-src="//lorempixel.com/60/60/food/3/" src="//lorempixel.com/60/60/food/3/">
    </div>
    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="http://localhost/product.html" title="Product">Product</a></h2>
</li>
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
            {
                jQuery(".moreviewslist img").click(function()
                {
                    jQuery(".MainImage").attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("data-main-image-src"));
                });
            });
```

JSFiddle example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/neocastelli/8YxnR/2/

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code below:

```
jQuery(".moreviewslist img").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().prev().find('img').attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("data-main-image-src"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Felix, another quick question, if i want to put the main image to the moreviewlist ?, i mean make a switch betwen images on click.

Comment: I don't get what you means. You want to move main image inside moreviewlist? Can you elaborate more on your question.

Comment: So, when you click the thumbnail image from bottom it change the main image, but the main image dissapear and i cannot switch back to the main image only if i refresh the page, so i think if on click the thumbnail, put the thumbnail data-main-image-src to the main image and main image to the data-main-image-src clicked.

Comment: when exactly do you want to change it to the `default/main` image?  Or are you looking just to toggle the images on each click?

Comment: The idea is: On click on image from moreviews (Change image and URL Source) and switch back to bottom moreviews the Image Source and URL) so later if i want to chose the first color.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have http for source you are replacing.you need to use:

```
 jQuery(".MainImage").attr("src","http:"+ jQuery(this).attr("data-main-image-src"));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8YxnR/3/)**

Comment: Hi Milind, thanks for the answer, yes, the images are just an example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to the `li` then use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to look for your `img.MainImage`

```
jQuery(".moreviewslist img").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('li').find('.MainImage').attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("data-main-image-src"));
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3P7zg/)